# Submitting and emailing an InfoPath quiz

Tags: infopath, calculated-column-formula, submit

I need the Submit button to email the quiz results and also submit the results to SharePoint.

I first used a rule button and created 2 rules, 1 to email and 1 to submit the form to SharePoint. It does email but it won't submit back to SharePoint. I also set the button options to close after it is pushed but it is also not doing that. If I use a submit button, I can do both.

However one step that I am also wanting to add is to have a section called score that uses a formula to calculate the score of the quiz on SharePoint. It seems that the formulas that SharePoint uses aren't the same as the formulas that InfoPath uses. I have all the formulas working for calculation in SharePoint and it works just fine. It's just the info path side.

I need a button that will do the following: Calculate the score and add it to the InfoPath form, submit it to SharePoint and also email the results. Then close the form.